# Use of conditional statements to classify output value

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have written a code in Python which outputs a single value and I want to classify that single output value depending on different conditions and ranges, which are:

[image]

I have tried the following but no output was printed:

```
if (Vk = 0):
       st = 'Ideal Homogenous'

if (0 < Vk < 0.25):
       st = 'Slightly Heterogenous'

if (0.25 < Vk < 0.50):
       st = ' Heterogenous'

if (0.50 < Vk < 0.75):
       st = 'Very Heterogenous'

if (0.75 < Vk < 1):
       st = 'Extremely Heterogenous'

if (Vk = 1):
       st = 'Perfectly Heterogenous'
```

Comment: Just add `print(st)` at the end. Also change the structure to a more convenient form: if... elif... elif... elif... etc

Comment: Python just stored the corresponding string in `st`. If you don't print it, you won't see anything in the console. You might also want to have a look to the `elif` statement to improve your code further.

Comment: st='', Vk==0, Vk==1, print(st) and check equivalence case as 0.50, 0.75 etc

Answer (score 1):

1. use == and not = for comperision inside if statements.

`if vk == 0:`

2. print the output using:

`print(st)`

3. notice for the value 0.25, 0.5, and 0.75 you will not get the desired output.
   you need to use >= or <= at least for one on the condition contain one of them.
4. it is better to use `elif` and `else` statements. this way the code will not check all cases all the time. when it will find the right answer it will skip all the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `print()` to display the output in your console. `=` is used for namespace assignment, `==`  is used to make comparison.

```
if (Vk == 0):
       st = 'Ideal Homogenous'

elif (0 < Vk < 0.25):
       st = 'Slightly Heterogenous'

elif (0.25 <= Vk < 0.50):
       st = ' Heterogenous'

elif (0.50 <= Vk < 0.75):
       st = 'Very Heterogenous'

elif (0.75 <= Vk < 1):
       st = 'Extremely Heterogenous'

elif (Vk == 1):
       st = 'Perfectly Heterogenous'

print(st)
```